# How to find a cell based on row and col criteria?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have a table like this:

```
  | a | b | c |
x | 1 | 8 | 6 |
y | 5 | 4 | 2 |
z | 7 | 3 | 5 |
```

What I want to do is finding a value based on the row and col titles, so for example if I have c&y, then it should return 2. What function(s) should I use to do this in OpenOffice Calc?

later:

I tried `=INDEX(B38:K67;MATCH('c';B37:K37;0);MATCH('y';A38:A67;0))`, but it writes invalid argument.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I wrote the arguments of `INDEX` in the wrong order. The `=INDEX(B38:K67;MATCH('y';A38:A67;0);MATCH('c';B37:K37;0))` formula works properly. The second argument is the row number and not the col number.